# What is the word for something getting received?

Tags: nouns

Can I use "receival" as a word (noun) for something that is received?
It is about drilling industry when drilling cutting is coming (receiving) to fill a special box. I want to write

> Receival feed rate is high.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you referring to waste material produced by (say) a drill going through metal?

Comment: Receival describes the activity more than the delivered quantity.

Comment: _Receipt_ (pronounced /rɪ'sit/ is one of the nouns formed from _receive_. It refers to the state of having received (_I am in receipt of your package_ means I have received it). But _receival_ is not.

Comment: Maybe *intake*? Industries usually have their own jargon for things.

Comment: I can not think of a 'single' word for "received goods".

Comment: Indeed I am seeking for a noun for receive...a noun for quantity or amount received. I think receipt would be correct. Any suggestion?

Comment: _Receipt_  is the action or fact of receiving something. It doesn't mean the thing that is received. Would _yield_ (as a noun meaning the quantity produced) work for you?

Comment: Whatever the drill generates is the product you can refer to: the oil feed rate, the woodchip feed rate, etc.

Comment: "feed rate" is normally the rate at which something goes out, not the rate at which it's received (this is maybe confusing because you think of feeding as equivalent to eating). Maybe "rate of receipt" or "input rate".